# delete the <br /> from the textarea?

Tags: php, textarea, line-breaks

I am trying to do a line break after the message "Original message", I have tried with this but It keeps showing me the

```
---Original message---<br />
message

<textarea id="txtMessage" rows="10" cols="50"><?php echo nl2br(str_replace('<br/>', " ","---Original message---\n".$array['message']));?></textarea>
```

I want something likes this:

```
---Original message---
message
```

any advise?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you read the [documentation on nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)?

Comment: So you try to get rid of `<br/>` and then MAKE them? That's nonsense. **Get rid of nl2br**, because it converts `\n` to `<br />`

Comment: sorry I didnt read the docs but now I understands

Comment: Adding more line breaks to the beginning should be easy - just add `\n` where ever you want one (for instance, change `---Original message---` to `\n\n---Original message---`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want it to:

```
<?php echo str_replace('<br />', " ","---Original message---\n".$array['message']);?>
```

---

> **nl2br** — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string ([from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php))

*Example:*

```
echo "<textarea>HI! \nThis is some String, \nit works fine</textarea>";
```

*Result:*

[image: new line example in textarea]

But if you try this:

```
echo nl2br("<textarea>HI! \nThis is some String, \nit works fine</textarea>");
```

you will get this:

[image: new line with nl2br in texarea]

Therefore **you should not use nl2br before saving it to database**, otherwise you have to get rid of `<br />` every time you try to edit text! Just use it when you print it out as text.

Comment: If I want to add blanks spaces before the text like 2 o more? thanks for answer

Comment: They will be ignored. Unless you use `&nbsp;`, which will be screwed on something like htmlspecialchars . Why would you like to use more then one space anyway?

Comment: Good job using my answer 30 minutes after me and getting the accept.

Comment: I see. Well i have no idea about the spaces

Comment: @AlienWebguy Well it took me a while to write it. No, i did not copy your answer

Comment: Compare our solutions, just saying. +1 for the added explanatory text.

Comment: They are the same, except i have the full code. Well I thought it will be accepted before i finished writing explanation, but apparently it wasn't. Besides, your point difference wouldn't be visible anyway :P

Answer (score 1):

```
echo nl2br(str_replace('<br/>', " ", ... ));
```

should be

```
echo str_replace('<br />', ' ', ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

The php function "nl2br" takes newlines, and converts them into br tags. If you don't want that, you should probably remove it :).

Heh, beaten by Ryan.

Comment: I removed and Its all but now If I want to add new lines in the beggining?? and then the rest

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to replace `<br/>`, but the original text has `<br />` (note the space).

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the HTML breaks, then adding them back! Look at your code:

```
nl2br(str_replace('<br/>', " ","---Original message---\n".$array['message']))
```

First, [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) replaces `'<br/>'` with a space. Then, [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br) adds a `<br>` for every newline (`\n`) it finds.

Remove `nl2br` call and it's done.

Comment: I removed and Its all but now If I want to add new lines in the beggining?? and then the rest

Comment: Add a `"\n"` character, surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: I tried in this way but It is the same effect <?php echo "\n"."---Original message---\n".$array['message'];?>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do nl2br on all of the text except for what's inside the textarea you could do this:

```
function clean_textarea_of_br($data) {
     return str_replace(array("<br>", "<br/>", "<br />"), "", $data[0]);
}

$message = preg_replace_callback('#<textarea[^>]*>(.*?)</textarea>#is',clean_textarea_of_br,$message);
```